# ruby on rails routing helper: how to create select_clients_path(client)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have client standard resource with CRUD, but I would like to make extension with action select, so that I can have select_clients_path(client).
In clients_controller I have created action select, but I dont know how to create correct routing rule

for now I have created:

```
  resources :clients do
        get 'select'
  end
```

but this generates /clients/select.2 but i would like somthing like /clients/select/2 or /clients/select?id=2

thank you

Dorijan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resources :clients do
  collection do
    get :select
  end
end
```

will create a 'clients/select' route, to which you can pass parameters like '?client_ids=2...' and work with several client records.

alternatively,

```
resources :clients do
  member do
    get :select
  end
end
```

will create a 'clients/:id/select' route to work with a single client record

Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions for more about this functionality, but those blocks will get you pretty far.